# MBCS to UTF-8 C++

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8

I'm working on a project in VS2008 that I'm compiling in MBCS but I need to work with some UTF-8 strings to interact with some web services. I wrote a function that works perfectly with Unicode but not MBCS. Is there any way I can convert a MBCS string to UTF-8 or to Unicode?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Convert the MBCS string to Unicode using [`MultiByteToWideChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072(VS.85).aspx) and then to UTF-8 with [`WideCharToMultiByte`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374130(VS.85).aspx). Pass `CP_ACP` to the first call and `CP_UTF8` to the second.

Comment: A good advice in general, but just pay attention that specifying CP_ACP is going to make the behavior dependent on the system language setting of the machine. If that is what he wants it is fine.

Comment: When convert MBCS to unicode, you need to have knowledge, on this MBCS is using which code page, right? (BIG5, Simplified Chinese...)

Comment: @Yan Cheng CHEOK, yes. However, most of the time the text will be in the active code page (all the text you retrieve from GUI is in that code page for example).